# Replacing a view in BigQuery : is there a "time hole"?

Tags: view, google-bigquery

There is no clear explanation in the documentation of what happens during a DDL statement in BigQuery. So, I would like to know :

1) When I replace a view (using `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW` ...) with a new definition, is there a "time hole" during which the old definition AND the new one are not available (sort of delete/create)?

2) What happens when a query is running and the view is replaced? Does it see the old definition, the new one, or none of them during the replacement?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

1. Replacement is atomic.
2. The view definition is retrieved when the job starts, and replacing it during execution doesn't affect the running job.